# Creating a diagram with quantity of values

Tags: latex, diagram

I'm trying to create a Diagram with following specification:

x-Axis: Values from file.

y-Axis: Quantity of the values

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ8CT.jpg) is an image to describe, what I need.

The order of the values is random.

I hope, anybody can help me with this problem.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ymin=0,
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      xlabel={values},
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel={amount of values}]
      \addplot table [ ... ,col sep=semicolon]  {data.csv};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of the three points shall be a command to calculate the y-values.
In the data-file are the values in one clolumn.

Comment: Can you add some more details on what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have searched a lot, but couldn't find anything to solve my problem. I don't know, how to count similar values to generate the y-axis.

Comment: I have added a code-example. I hope it shows enough details.